# Enumerate each group

Tags: python-polars

Starting with

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]})
```

how can I get a column which numbers the `'group'` column?

Here's what `df` looks like:

```py
shape: (8, 1)
┌───────┐
│ group │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4     │
└───────┘
```

and here's my expected output:

```py
shape: (8, 2)
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ group ┆ group_i │
│ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ i64   ┆ i64     │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3     ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3     ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3     ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4     ┆ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4     ┆ 2       │
└───────┴─────────┘
```

---

Here's one way I came up with, it just feels a bit complex for this task...is there a simpler way?

```py
 df.with_column(((pl.col('group')!=pl.col('group').shift()).cast(pl.Int64).cumsum()-1).alias('group_i'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the terms come from SQL:

You're looking to [`.rank()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rank.html) your data - in particular - a `"dense"` ranking.

```
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col("group").alias("group_i").rank("dense") - 1)
shape: (8, 2)
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ group | group_i │
│ ---   | ---     │
│ i64   | u32     │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│ 1     | 0       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 1     | 0       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 1     | 0       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 3     | 1       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 3     | 1       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 3     | 1       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 4     | 2       │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ 4     | 2       │
└───────┴─────────┘
```